# Переход по следующему id

Tags: php

Я собрал `id` и хотел сделать для них ссылки для переходов назад/вперед. Как это можно сделать?
Вот в этом примере `$id` содержит `24 23 20 18 87 6`:

```
$idcontent = $this->article->getAllArticlesName($_GET["login"]);
for($i = 0;$i < count($idcontent); $i++){
    $id = $idcontent[$i]["id"];
    print_r($id);
}
```

Comment: Предоставьте больше информации по вашему вопросу, в частности, сообщите, что вы подразумеваете под "сделать для них ссылки для переходов назад вперед". Больше внимания, а главное - ответов, собирают те вопросы, которые были заданы грамотно, исчерпывающе, чтобы не приходилось переспрашивать и уточнять детали в комментариях.

Comment: Вот этот вариянт только плюсует  id +1, и идет переход к следующему,НО теперь нетак

Comment: $sr["next"] = $this->config->address."?view=article&amp;id=".($sr["id"] - 1);
  $sr["prev"] = $this->config->address."?view=article&amp;id=".($sr["id"] + 1);

Comment: Это id страниц определенного пользователя , каким-то образом переключения должны идти в этом порядке 24 23 20 18 87 6:

Comment: $sr["next"]  адрес url

Answer (score -2):

Что бы получить новости у которых id больше 3, 5, 9, нам нужно:
Поместить идентификаторы в массив.

Пройтись циклом по массиву, и найти ближающий id, который выше текущего, при этом помещая каждую новую найденную новость в массив.

После этого,мы можем делать с массивом что захотим.

```
$array = ['3', '5', '9'];

foreach($array as $q)
{
    $nextNews[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id > $q LIMIT 1"));
}

var_dump($nextNews);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: Это ваш совет очень вредный. Предлагаете в цикле долбить базу запросами там где достаточно одного?

Comment: Хотя бы что-то за два дня.

Я понимаю что он вредный,и есть более хорошие решения, например тот же WHERE IN, но я пока чот не понял как сделать WHERE IN(15,20,30 > текущего ида.).

Comment: Ну наверняка эта выборка id (в вопросе) это уже последовательность новостей следующих друг за другом. Следовательно надо определить только предыдущую для первой и следующую для последней...